# Subtype constraint for the OBJECT IDENTIFIER type: How to constrain an OID to some arc?

Tags: constraints, asn.1, subtype

I am writing a specification in ASN.1. What is the formally correct syntax to restrict the range of values of an attribute with type `OBJECT IDENTIFIER` to a particular OID arc? E.g. I would like to achieve something like

```
foo OBJECT IDENTIFIER ( BELOW SUBTREE { 2 1 1 } )
```

The keyword `BELOW SUBTREE` has been made up by me for the sake of an example to make clear what I am looking for.

*Elaborated example*

Seemingly, my question above is not sufficiently clear as some answers suggest solutions that do not address the problem.  I'll elaborate a little bit more on what I am doing and what I want to achieve. I am writing a X.509 certificate policy and must specify a X.509 profile in chapter 7. This means I have to substantiate some choices or degree of freedom which exist in the general syntax for the scope of my application. Especially, I cannot nor must not change any attribute types because this would make the result incompatible to a X.509 certificate, i.e. I can only specialize some types as long as the specialization remains compatible to the generalization.

Object identifiers are used all over the place in X.509.

As a tangible example, let's take the attribute `policyIdentifier` whose type is an alias of `OBJECT IDENTIFIER` within the object of type `PolicyInformation` within the certificate extention `CertificatePolicies`.

```
CertificatePolicies ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1) OF PolicyInformation

PolicyInformation ::= SEQUENCE {
  policyIdentifier   CertPolicyId,
}

CertPolicyId ::= OBJECT IDENTIFIER
```

(I have already shortened down the ASN.1 syntax to the needs of my application.)

Let's assume I have defined the following constants

```
id-cp-my-policies OBJECT IDENTIFIER -- some OID arc in the private enterprise arc under my control
id-cp-my-policy-v10 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-cp-my-policies 1 0 }
id-cp-my-policy-v11 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-cp-my-policies 1 1 }
id-cp-my-policy-v12 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-cp-my-policies 1 2 }
id-cp-my-policy-v20 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-cp-my-policies 2 0 }
id-cp-my-policy-v30 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-cp-my-policies 3 0 }
id-cp-my-policy-v31 OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-cp-my-policies 3 1 }
```

I want to express that `CertPolicyId` is a specialization of `OBJECT IDENTIFIER` which can only take values from the list above. Of course, I could explicitly enumerate all policy IDs by the "OR"-sytax, i.e. I could write

```
CertPolicyId ::= OBJECT IDENTIFIER ( id-cp-my-policy-v10 | id-cp-my-policy-v11 | id-cp-my-policy-v12 | id-cp-my-policy-v20 | id-cp-my-policy-v30 | id-cp-my-policy-v31 )
```

However, this does not seem very future-proof. Instead, I would like to write something like

```
CertPolicyId ::= OBJECT IDENTIFIER ( BELOW SUBTREE id-cp-my-policies )
```

I hope this example helps to understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 4):

There is no formal way to constrain the OBJECT IDENTIFIER type to fall under a certain arc.

Comment: Really? :-( That's a pity. I'll wait if anybody comes up with a solution and proves your answer wrong. If not, I'll eventually accept this answer although it is not what I hoped for.

Comment: Kevin's answer is correct. In ASN.1 there is no constraint that restricts the values of an object identifier type to begin with a specified series of integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RELATIVE-OID type

You can either make the root oid implicit (let's say foo is a component of a SEQUENCE)

```
{
  foo RELATIVE-OID  -- relative to root { 2 1 1 }
}
```

or explicit

```
{ 
   foo SEQUENCE {
      root OBJECT IDENTIFIER DEFAULT { 2 1 1 },
      object-id RELATIVE-OID  -- relative to root
   }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to give a reference to the specs which define the RELATIVE-OID type? I haven't heard of it before.

Comment: This is defined in TREC X.680 (https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.680-X.693-201508-I).

Comment: After reading the specs, I figured out that this type is not what I am looking for. The RELATIVE-OID is only a mechanism to reduce the size of the communicstion by only transmitting the tail of an OID given that a common prefix is understood by and shared among all communication partners. The common prefix is somehow determined by the upper layers of the application and might be noted by a comment in ASN.1. However, I need to transmit the whole OID, not only a part of it, but I want to express that the OID must meet from a specific arc.

Comment: After your editing of the question, I think @Kevin answer is the correct one ...

Comment: The usual suggestion is to specify the restriction (in your own format or in English text) in a user-defined constraint. For example:

O ::= OBJECT IDENTIFIER (CONSTRAINED BY {--below arc-- OBJECT IDENTIFIER : {0 1 2 3}})

Obviously, the above constraint cannot be automatically enforced unless the ASN.1 tool supports custom callbacks for user-defined constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
foo OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { 1 2 3 }
foo-bar OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { foo 4 }
```

thus, `foo-bar` will result in `1.2.3.4` OID value in dotted notation. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This is a way to define values, not types.  He seems to want to define a type.

Comment: No, that is not what I am looking for. I know how define a value (or constant). As @Kevin has stated correctly, I want to define a restricted type which enforces an attribute only accept OIDs below a particular arc.